# Keyboard Notification Not Firing Properly

Tags: iphone

I am trying to get a notification when the keyboard is about to be displayed, but currently it is firing AFTER showing the keyboard.

Here is my notification registration:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector (keyboardDidShow:)
     name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
     object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector (keyboardDidHide:)
     name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
     object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector (keyboardDidShow:)
     name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
     object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector (keyboardDidHide:)
     name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
     object:nil];
```

Changing `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`